# Calculate the clausure of $A=\{(x,f(x)) \in G(f): x < f(x) \}$

Tags: general-topology, functions

Let $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ an increasing function such that $f(x) \neq x$, $G(f)$ the graph of function $f$. Calculate the clousure of the following sets: $$A=\{(x,f(x)) \in G(f): x < f(x) \}$$ $$B=\{(x,f(x)) \in G(f): x > f(x) \}$$

What I tried is prove $cl(A)= \{(x,f(x)) \in G(f) : x \leq f(x)\}$ and $cl(B)=\{(x,f(x)) \in G(f) : x \geq f(x)\}$, but I'm not sure about it. Could you help me to prove it or calculate the correct set?.

Thanks four your help.

Comment: You cannot find the closure of $A$ wihtout further hypothesis..

Comment: Is $f$ continuous?  Do you know if $x$ is every less than $f(x)$.  If $x$ is ever equal to $f(x)$.  If $x$ is ever greater than $f(x)$?  Maybe $A$ is already closed?  Maybe $A$ is empty?

Comment: Is $f$ is arbitrary, the closure of $A$ could be the whole plane, or empty. No way of knowing.

Comment: Consider $f(x) =x - 1$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x)=x+1$ if $x$ is irrational.  Then $A =\{(x,x-1)|x\in \mathbb Q\}$ and $cl(A) = \{(x,x-1)|x\in \mathbb R\}$.  But $B=\{(x,f(x))|x \le f(x)\} = \{(x,x-1)|x\in \mathbb Q\} = A$.

Comment: Also consider if $f$ is continuous but $f(x) = 0$ if $f(x) = x;$ if $x < 0$ but $x = 2x$ if $x \ge 0$. Then $A = \{(0,2x)|x > 0\}$ and $cl(A) = \{(0,2x|x \ge 0\}$.  But $B=\{(x,f(x))|x \le f(x)\} = \{(x,f(x))| x\in \mathbb R\}$.